# Migrate google analytics app project to web project

Tags: analytics, google-analytics-api

Google recently announced of disabling google analytics for mobile app and moving
to firebase analytics
Can I Change my mobile project in analytics to web project?
And if not, can I export my data to another analytics tool?

thanks